# AWS IAM: programmatic access via AWS webpage results an IAM user without `access key ID`. I need it for S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, django-settings

I'm trying to create an IAM user that can be used for my Django project for serving static files with AWS S3 (also, locally).
For that I need to fill blanks in my Django's **settings.py**:

```
"""
AWS-specific settings for S3 with Boto3 library
"""
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = "django-foo-python-bucket"
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = "eu-west-3"
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "1234567890"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "" # Here is the problem discussed in this question
```

The problem I have is the following: when I create an IAM user with settings:

[image: My settings]

I receive a user with `Access key ID` == `None`
In my **.csv** file that I could download after I created a user, instead of *User name,Password,Access key ID*, I have: *User name,Password,Console sign-in URL*

[image: Access key ID None]

I don't have a lot of experience with IAM so I don't know what to do.
I was trying to find some pieces of information somewhere, but the documentation is too abstract at this point for me. I found a tutorial that seemed to work (at least for its author), but it's outdated and now the page has different content and fields. When the tutorial was made, the page looked like this (it's the same page as on my first picture - it's almost certainly the same page):

[image: past version of AWS IAM]

The author of this old tutorial received **.csv** with: *User name,Password,Access key ID*.
How to receive Acces key ID today? Why my output differs from his?

Comment: `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` is showed only once, when you create a user. You can generate new access key if you lost it. But its generally  a bad practice to hardcode aws keys in your application. Normally you would use instance role instead for that.

Comment: After you create the user, you can create an access key for the user under the "Security credentials" in the settings for the users.  That said, if you're running the server on an EC2 instance, you should use an instance role.